# Converter string para data

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer com que uma função incremente X dias a uma data. O problema é que a data está vindo como `string` nesse formato: `dd/mm/yyyy` e na hora de atribuir o X dias a essa data, diz que não reconhece a var que será incrementada em X dias, como: `var_tal is not a function`. Como eu procedo? [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/pnet/ed3m6t4o/1/) está o exemplo no fiddle.

Dessa forma não funciona:

```
var dt_exclusao = '26/11/2015';
var periodo = 60;
var nova_data = new Date(dt_exclusao);
    //alert(dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo));
    alert(nova_data);
    alert(periodo);
    nova_data.setDate(nova_data.getDate() + periodo);
    alert(nova_data);
```

Mas assim funciona, isso quer dizer que é o formato passado que reside o problema:

```
var dt_exclusao = '2015-11-26T00:00:00';
var periodo = 60;
var nova_data = new Date(dt_exclusao);
    //alert(dt_exclusao.setDate(dt_exclusao.getDate() + periodo));
    alert(nova_data);
    alert(periodo);
    nova_data.setDate(nova_data.getDate() + periodo);
    alert(nova_data);
```

No fiddle funcionou, mas na página não. A função na página está assim:

```
function montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(dt_exclusao, periodo){

    var arrData = dt_exclusao.split('/');
    var novaData = new Date(arrData[2] + '-' + arrData[1] + '-' + arrData[0]);

    alert(arrData);
    alert(dt_exclusao);
    alert(periodo);
    alert(novaData);
    novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + periodo);
    alert(novaData);    
}
```

A grande diferença é que `fiddle` eu coloco na mão o `dt_exclusao` e na função eu recebo. A data montada em `novaData` vem assim: `NaN`. O `arrData` está correto, tipo: 26,11,2015, mas a montagem dá erro `NaN`.

Comment: Não adianta passar `dd/mm/yyyy` para `new Date()`. Você já achou um formato alternativo que é aceito, por que não usá-lo?

Comment: @bfavaretto, a data já vem de uma outra função que pega do banco nesse formato `dd/mm/yyyy`todo o meu problema é que eu não estou conseguindo transformar de um formato`(string - dd/mm/yyyy)` para o aceito. Esse é o motivo do post.

Comment: Quebre o valor com split como sugeriu o Pedro

Comment: No seu fiddle, não há objeto Date, não irá funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Em realidade essa é outra pergunta, ainda que para a mesma função. Aqui eu pergunto com relação a como passar de string para data, logo não foi respondida ainda.

Comment: Não? O Pedro Camara Junior explica exatamente como fazer.

Comment: Não tinha visto a discussão aqui, está funcionando agora @pnet ?

Comment: Mas aqui tem o fiddle funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/8hz20pkL/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O construtor `new Date()` com string deve ser no formato `mm-dd-yyyy` ou `mm/dd/yyyy` ou pode ainda utilizar o construtor com inteiros `new Date(yyyy, mm, dd)`

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

No teu caso, você precisa converter a string para um desses formatos, pode fazer isso utilizando o [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), e depois acessar os valores do array gerado para utilizar no construtor que prefirir.

> **Nota**: Quando usar construtor com inteiros, o mês começa em `0`, por isso adicionei no construtor `-1`.

```js
var dataExclusao = '26/11/2015';
var arrDataExclusao = dataExclusao.split('/');

var stringFormatada = arrDataExclusao[1] + '-' + arrDataExclusao[0] + '-' +
  arrDataExclusao[2];
var dataFormatada1 = new Date(stringFormatada);
var dataFormatada2 = new Date(arrDataExclusao[2], arrDataExclusao[1] - 1, arrDataExclusao[0]);

console.log('Data formatada 1: ' + dataFormatada1);
console.log('Data formatada 2: ' + dataFormatada2);

dataFormatada1.setDate(dataFormatada1.getDate() + 60);
dataFormatada2.setDate(dataFormatada2.getDate() + 90);

console.log('Data formatada + 60 dias: ' + dataFormatada1);
console.log('Data formatada + 90 dias: ' + dataFormatada2);
```

Answer (score 11):

O construtor `Date` (bem como o método [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)) é bem restrito no [formato aceito](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14). O formato é esse que você citou:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

O `Z` refere-se ao fuso horário UTC. Tem browser que até aceita outros formatos, mas como eles [não são mencionados na especificação](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), é melhor usar esse mesmo.

Uma alternativa a esse formato é passar as partes da data como parâmetros separados:

```
var hoje = new Date(2015, 10, 26);
```